# Astrojs: How can I get a component to appear as inline text in an MDX file?

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs, mdxjs

Question:
In the screenshot below, I want the first line to appear exactly as the second line. Is there a way to do this in Astrojs?

Here is my full reproduction on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-silence-bzg165?file=/src/pages/mdxpage.mdx).

Here is what the output looks like (see below). Notice how the period has a space before the word "text" in the first line and the second line does not have a space. The reason this is happening is because there is a line break after the end `</div>` element in the html in the first example. I need to figure a way to prevent the line break from happening.

[image]

Here are the contents of my mdx file:

```
---

---
import Inline from "./components/Inline.astro";

<div>Here is <Inline text="some text"/>. to inline</div>

<div>Here is <div style="display:inline">some text</div>. to inline</div>
```

And here are the contents of the `Inline.astro` component:

```
---
interface Props {
  text: string;
}

const { text } = Astro.props;
---

<div>{text}</div>

<style>
  div {
    display: inline;
  }
</style>
```

I have tried using a `<span>` element instead of a `<div>`, but this did not change anything. My use case is to create Astro components that appear inline within text blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, I created a separate `Paragraph` component that strips out all line breaks:

The `Paragraph.astro` file:

```
---
const html = (await Astro.slots.render("default")).replace(/[\r\n]/gm, "");
---

<div set:html={html} />
```

The I can just wrap my inline content like so:

```
<Paragraph>Here is <Inline text="some text"/>. to inline</Paragraph>
```